# Editable 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, class, for-loop, nullpointerexception

I want to create a 2D Array that creates a mini seating chart of an airplane. So far, I've gotten it to successfully print out something that looks like this:

> 1A(0)  ||  1B(0)   || 1C(0)
>
> 2A(0)  ||  2B(0)   || 2C(0)
>
> 3A(0)  ||  3B(0)   || 3C(0)
>
> 4A(0)  ||  4B(0)   || 4C(0)

The zeroes represent an empty seat, and the number one is used to represent an occupied seat.

I first created the program with arrays that were class variables for a First Class, but I wanted to make this program usable for an Economy Class section. The only difference between the two sections is the size of the array so I edited my code to look like this:

```
public class Seating
 { 
 private int FIRSTCLASS= 12; 
 private int ECONOMYCLASS= 240;
 private int occupied, column;
 private String[][] seatchart;
 private int[][] seatlist;
 private String[][] namelist;
 private String name; 
 public String customer;

public Seating(String seatclass) 
{ 
    seatclass.toUpperCase();
    if (seatclass.equals("FIRSTCLASS"))
    { 
      seatchart= new String[FIRSTCLASS/3][3];
      seatlist= new int[FIRSTCLASS/3][3];
      namelist= new String[FIRSTCLASS/3][3];
    }
    else 
    if (seatclass.equals("ECONOMY"))
    { 
      seatchart= new String[ECONOMYCLASS/3][3];
      seatlist= new int[ECONOMYCLASS/3][3];
      namelist= new String[ECONOMYCLASS/3][3];
    }   

}
public void Creation()
 {
   for (int i=0; i< seatlist.length; i++) 
    {  
        for (int j=0; j<seatlist[i].length; j++) 
        { 
            seatlist[i][j]= 0 ;

        }
    }
```

I get an null pointer exception error around  `for (int i=0; i< seatlist.length; i++)`
How can I fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
seatclass.toUpperCase();
```

Replace it with:

```
seatclass = seatclass.toUpperCase();
```

I think you are creating the class with a string like "firstclass" rather than "FIRSTCLASS" right? Those aren't the same strings and just invoking the toUpperCase method on the string without assigning the result to a variable to then be tested means nothing happens.

Then since none of your if conditions are met, the arrays are not initialized and a null pointer exception is thrown when Completion() is called.

I'm not sure if you are new to java programming, but I wanted to add a few recommendations to your class:

```
public class Seating {

 private static int FIRSTCLASS= 12;    // Make these constants static since they pertain to all 
 private static int ECONOMYCLASS= 240; // instances of your class. That way there is exactly on
                                       // copy of the variables, which is more memory efficient.
 private int occupied;
 private column;  // Okay but Java convention is to declare each member variable on its own line
                  // increases code readability.
 private String[][] seatchart;
 private int[][] seatlist;
 private String[][] namelist;
 private String locSeatClass;
 private String name;

 public String customer; // Okay but better to leave this private and then provide getter and
                         // setter methods to provide access to this string. Much easier to track
                         // down who is changing its value in your code.

public Seating(String seatclass) { // Java convention is to place the opening bracket here not
                                   // on the next line.  
    // Make sure that seatClass is not null or empty. NOTE: This is a neat trick for
    // simultaneously checking for both null and empty strings in one shot. Otherwise, you have
    // you have to check for null and then examine the string's length which is more code.
    if ("".equalsIgnoreCase(seatClass) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Seat class undefined.");
    }

    // Store the seat class in a member variable for use. Could also be a local variable.
    // My original solution is problematic because it changes the original value of the seat
    // class that was passed into the constructor (you might want that information).
    locSeatClass = seatclass.toUpperCase();

    if (locSeatClass.equals("FIRSTCLASS"))
    { 
      seatchart= new String[FIRSTCLASS/3][3];
      seatlist= new int[FIRSTCLASS/3][3];
      namelist= new String[FIRSTCLASS/3][3];
    }
    else if (locSeatclass.equals("ECONOMY")) { 
      seatchart= new String[ECONOMYCLASS/3][3];
      seatlist= new int[ECONOMYCLASS/3][3];
      namelist= new String[ECONOMYCLASS/3][3];
    }
    else {
        // Throw an exception if someone passes in an unknown seat class string.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown seat class detected.")
    }  

}

public void creation() { // NOTE: Java convention is to begin method names with a lower 
                         // case letter.

   // This method is unnecessary. Arrays of integers are initialized with an initial value
   // of zero by default. However, if you want to make your class reusable, you could change
   // change the name of the this method to clear, which would allow you to clear the arrays of
   // an existing object.
   for (int i=0; i< seatlist.length; i++) 
    {  
        for (int j=0; j<seatlist[i].length; j++) 
        { 
            seatlist[i][j]= 0 ;

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks! I realized that and after I corrected it it compiles and works fine :)

Comment: Uhm, no big deal, but I think my answer is THE answer. Mr. Hopp's is good advice, certainly.

Comment: Sorry I accepted his answer before I saw yours! I didn't know you could change the selected answer, but I changed it :)

Comment: Nichi, Didn't have time to comment completely last night, but I wanted to make a few recommendations. See above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just started programming this year so the recommendations really helped! Thanks for taking the time to help (:

Answer (score 2):

The only way that line of code can generate a NPE is if `seatlist` is `null`. Unless you assign `null` to `seatlist` somewhere else in your class, the only way it can be `null` is if the argument that you pass to the `Seating` constructor does not match either `"FIRSTCLASS"` or `"ECONOMY"`. Check your call to the constructor. Also, you might want to just use `seatclass.equalsIgnoreCase()`.

You should modify your constructor to at least warn about that eventuality, since it is vital to the proper operation of the class that any instances of `Seating` have valid `seatlist` and `namelist` arrays.

Comment: I didn't look at my code carefully and I misused the .toUpperCase() in the code. I'll remember to look carefully at my code next time.. and thanks for the tip :)